# Airflow API POST trigger new dag run conf splits payload

Tags: python, airflow

I am using `requests` to POST to trigger a new DAG run in Airflow.

However I set the conf payload. But when it gets passed to my script that is executed in Airflow, it has some how split the json string. I have a work around where I join it. But surely this should not happen.

For example in my python code I make the request like so:

```
data = {
    'my_data': {
        'id': '1',
        'firstName': 'John',
        'lastName': 'Smith'
    }
}

body = {
    "conf": {
        "data": data
    },
}
headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
req = requests.post(
    url=f"https://example_url.com/api/v1/dags/my_dag_id/dagRuns",
    data=json.dumps(body),
    auth=("admin", os.getenv("AIRFLOW_PASSWORD")),
    headers=headers
)
```

This posts fine and triggers the new dag.

My python script then gets passed the `conf` via an Airflow K8 pod operator like so:

```
processor = KubernetesPodOperator(
    image="my_image_url",
    cmds=["bash"],
    arguments=["-c", "python3 -m processer {{ dag_run.conf['data'] }}"],
    name="processor",
    task_id="processor",
    container_resources=resources_w_gpu,
    **common_options
)
```

Then the script executes from `__main__` like so:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
        try:
            logger.info(sys.argv[1:])
            data = json.loads(sys.argv[1:])
            main(data)
        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()
            logger.error(str(e))
```

But currently this throws a type error for the `json.loads(sys.argv[1:])`:

`TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not list`

So I added the logger above to see what is going on and it logged this:

`['{my_data:', '{id:', '1,', 'firstName:', 'John,', 'lastName:', 'Smith']`

It seems it has split somehow on the commas.

A way I hacked it to work was use `replace('"', '\\"')` here:

```
body = {
    "conf": {
        "data": json.dumps(data).replace('"', '\\"')
    },
}
```

Then back in my script in the main block I joined like so:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
        data = json.loads(" ".join(sys.argv[1:]))
        main(data)
```

But surely airflow should handle this better?

Comment: the problem is in the bash cli. try to add single quote in the args around the json: "python3 -m processer '{{ dag_run.conf['data'] }}'"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the bash cli that split each space to an different argument.

you need to put double quote around the dag_run.conf['data'] . this way the bash would get it as one argument and python would know to read it back.

I suggest to work with module **click** when working with cli and arguments

```
arguments=["-c", 'python3 -m processer "{{ dag_run.conf["data"] }}"'],
```

Comment: Same issue...wish it was that! I even tried escaping the data commas but no joy

Comment: yes, i see the problem. replace ' with ", or use module click in processer. if you sorrond it with single quote python does not see it as one statement but with double it will